# mysql ft_stopword_file question

Tags: mysql, search, path, full-text-search

This is really embarrassing but I can't get the stopword file to function as I want in mysql.    My mysql base dir in my my.cnf is /usr and my server's root directory is below that.  My my.cnf file is located at /etc/mysql/my.cnf

I name the stopword file stop.txt and have placed it in the /usr folder, the /etc/mysql/ folder, and the root directory.  In my.cnf I have tried setting ft_stopword_file to /stop.txt and stop.txt. Neither of those work but surely that path must refer to one of those locations.

After setting the path each time I reboot the server and repair the table.  But no dice.

Any advice?  Sorry this is such a dumb relative path question and I can't believe I've psent 2 hours staring at the screen.

Comment: You may have better luck with this on ServerFault.com

Answer (score 0):

You need not to repair table, but to rebuild FULLTEXT indexes.

Comment: Yep, I do repair table quick which I think just rebuilds the index